# How to quickly generate the values satisfying the given condition?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, compile, sampling

Consider some domains in variables `th`, `z` and some condition `cond` defining the domain of a variable `ph` for the given `th`, `z`:

```
thmin = ArcTan[(5 - 1.5)/515];
thmax = ArcTan[Sqrt[(5 + 1.5)^2 + 1.5^2]/480];
cond[th_, ph_, z_] = 
 Boole[-6.5 < z*Sin[th]/Cos[th] Cos[ph] < -3.5 && -1.5 < 
    z*Sin[th]/Cos[th] Sin[ph] < 1.5]
zmin = 480.;
zmax = 515.;
```

*Given the boundaries in z, in the given example, `cond` is actually a condition for the box `-6.5 < x < -3.5 && -1.5 < y < 1.5 && 480 < z < 515`. However, I have data in polar angles `th` as an input; also the shape of `cond` may be arbitrary.*

My goal is, for the given values of `th`,

```
randomth = RandomReal[{thmin, thmax}, 10^6];
```

(in the real case, they are not random), to generate random values of `ph`, `z` for which `cond` will be satisfied.

I use a brute-force approach by generating random values of `ph` and `z` and checking if, for the given `th`, they satisfy `cond`:

```
phvals1 = 
  Hold@Compile[{{randomth, _Real}}, 
          Module[{if = 0., phv = 0., zval = zmin},
           While[if == 0.,
            phv = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}];
            zval = RandomReal[{zmin, zmax}];
            
            If[randomth > 1.01 thmin && randomth < 0.99 thmax, 
             if = cond[randomth, phv, zval]];
            (*Some values of th may satisfy cond only at the \
boundaries in z, 
            so the following two conditions are needed in order to \
avoid infinite loop stuck*)
            If[randomth < 1.01 thmin,
             if = cond[randomth, phv, zmax];
             zval = zmax;];
            If[randomth > 0.99 thmax,
             if = cond[randomth, phv, zmin];
             zval = zmin;];
            ];
           {randomth, phv, zval}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
          RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
          Parallelization -> True] /. DownValues@cond /. 
       OwnValues@zmin /. OwnValues@zmax /. OwnValues@thmin /. 
    OwnValues@thmax // ReleaseHold;
(*<<CompiledFunctionTools` 
CompilePrint@phvals1;*)
```

The result is not fast and shows some artifacts:

```
data = phvals1[randomth]; // AbsoluteTiming
coords = {#[[3]]/Cos[#[[1]]] Sin[#[[1]]] Cos[#[[2]]], #[[3]]/
      Cos[#[[1]]] Sin[#[[1]]] Sin[#[[2]]], #[[3]]} & /@ data;
ListPointPlot3D[coords]
```

[image]

Could you please tell me how to speed it up and make it more robust?

**Edit**
I may simply exclude the values of `randomth` that are closer to the boundary than some margin that is acceptable to me, e.g., `0.995 thmax` and `1.005 thmin`. The following code will then be working without other extra things:

```
randomth = RandomReal[{1.005 thmin, 0.995 thmax}, 10^6];
phvals2 = 
  Hold@Compile[{{randomth, _Real}}, 
          Module[{if = 0., phv = 0., zval = zmin}, While[if == 0.,
            phv = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}];
            zval = RandomReal[{zmin, zmax}];
            if = cond[randomth, phv, zval];
            (*If[randomth>1.01 thmin&&randomth<0.99 thmax,if=cond[
            randomth,phv,zval]];
            (*Some values of th may satisfy cond only at the \
boundaries in z,
            so the following two conditions are needed in order to \
avoid infinite loop stuck*)If[randomth<1.01 thmin,if=cond[randomth,
            phv,zmax];
            zval=zmax;];
            If[randomth>0.99 thmax,if=cond[randomth,phv,zmin];
            zval=zmin;];*)];
           {randomth, phv, zval}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
          RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
          Parallelization -> True] /. DownValues@cond /. 
       OwnValues@zmin /. OwnValues@zmax /. OwnValues@thmin /. 
    OwnValues@thmax // ReleaseHold;
(*<<CompiledFunctionTools` CompilePrint@phvals2;*)
```

Comment: I'm confused. I tried your code and got `cond[randomth[[1]], result[[1, 1]], result[[1, 2]]]` is 0. Do you know if this condition can even be satisfied? This suggests otherwise: `FindInstance[-6.5 < z*Tan[th] Cos[ph] < -3.5 && -1.5 < 
   z*Tan[th] Sin[ph] < 1.5
  && thmin <= th <= thmax && zmin <= z <= zmax && -Pi <= ph <= Pi
 , {z, ph, th}, RandomSeeding -> 123]`

Comment: @flinty : yes, e.g., `cond[0.009, 0.9*Pi, 485]`.

Comment: @flinty : if defining this condition in Cartesian coordinates, it would be simply a rectangle: `-6.5 < x < -3.5 && -1.5 < y - 1.5`. The problem is that I have data in terms of polar angle.

Comment: Why not just generate points via `points = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{thmin,thmax},{phmin,phmax},{zmin,zmax}}], numPoints]` then do `Select[points, (cond@@#) == 1&]` ?

Comment: @flinty : I need to have exactly `Length[randomh]` points.

Comment: `numPoints = Length[randomh]` then? Or do you mean that's how many points you need that satisfy the condition? In which case just repeat the procedure and Reap / Sow in a loop until you have that many points.

Comment: @flinty : I have the given `randomth`, and for each value of `th`, I need to find exactly one combination of `z`, `ph`.